# can't move focus to the control in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am having an issue with ie and focusing on a form designed around jquery ui. I turned the input fields into buttons to get the button effect. I have the page focus on the username field in a login popup as soon as it loads. This works in chrome  & firefox but not ie, I get this error:
`can't move focus to the control` in the bottom left corner. The link to the page is here: https://aliahealthcare.com/STNA_Applicationfull.php . Any help would be great, thanks!

I have tried the set time out, and that did not work. This was the only real solution I could find in my research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to validate your page. Their are some tag issues, among other problems. Any time IE has tag issues around a form it can cause all sorts of funky behavior and submittal problems

[W3C Validation of page](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=https%3A%2F%2Faliahealthcare.com%2FSTNA_Applicationfull.php)

Comment: so what was the answer? StackOverflow is a community. Please help others by detailing the problem and solution. Simply marking as answered with a contradictory comment helps no one.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at your inputs.  i see:

```
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" style="font-size::30px;"/>
<input name="password" type="password" id="password" style="font-size::30px;"/>
```

there are extra colons in your "font-size" style rule.  try removing those and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I didnt notice that, thanks. However after removing them there is no change. Thanks.

Comment: no problem.  when i loaded your page again, i received this error in IE:   Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.1; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 18 Jun 2012 03:43:15 UTC

**
Message: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.
Line: 3
Char: 3501
Code: 0
URI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js  -- so it's not possible to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ya that is the error I have been getting. I did a set time out because i read somewhere IE has an issue with repainting the DOM which causes that error and a time out would fix that issue however it is not fixing it in my case.